# Problems installing Octave packages GSL and libinterp

Tags: package, octave

I'm trying to install the Octave packages GSL 2.1.1 and libinterp 0.1.0. I downloaded the .tar.gz for GSL and did `package install gsl-2.1.1` and things appeared to be going well until:

`checking for ov-scalar.h... no
pkg: error running the configure script for gsl.
error: called from 'configure_make' in file C:\Octave\O
ctave-4.0.0\share\octave\4.0.0\m\pkg\private\configure_
make.m near line 79, column 9`

I searched to see what ov-scalar.h was and it looked like it was part of libinterp, so I downloaded that and tried to install it with`pkg install libinterp-0.1.0.tar.gz`, but this time I got

`package is missing file: DESCRIPTION
error: called from 'verify_directory' in file C:\Octave
\Octave-4.0.0\share\octave\4.0.0\m\pkg\private\verify_d
irectory.m near line 30, column 7`

Can anyone help me figure out the issues here? At the end of the day I just want access to some special functions.

EDIT: I accidentally said I called `package load gsl-2.1.1` rather than `package install gsl-2.1.1`. I did the latter.

Comment: I would suggest to install Octave 4.4.1 and first habe a look (pkg list) if the GSL package already is included

Comment: It does; thank you! It's nice that all these are now included in the new version, which I hadn't realized was available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is:

```
package load gsl
```

and it is for loading package already installed.
If you use a preinstalled binary, gsl is already available.
The last version for `octave 4.4.1` has `gsl 2.1.1`

https://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Microsoft_Windows

Please note that `libinterp` is integral part of `octave`, so there is no reason to try to install it separately.

Comment: Thank you! I miswrote in the question and have corrected it with an edit. Besides, the error message I copied wasn't a message for a missing package.